# Does circumcision go against Allah's creative will?

Tags: quran, hadith

In [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/why-is-circumcision-required-in-islam) question it was asked why circumcision is required, and the answers make it clear that the prophet(pbuh) says that Muslim men should remove their foreskin. I don't understand this since

**وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)**

Isn't it contradictory for Islam to acknowledge Allah as being all knowing and wise in what he creates and wills to be, yet at the same time recommending to remove the foreskin and change what he has created for every newborn male child?

Comment: Please review your definition of blasphemy.  I have no idea how you can think this is blasphemy.  Either way, please remember that Allah is most merciful.  What you do out of ignorance will be forgiven.

Comment: ok, I've removed the reference to blasphemy since this is a deliberate insulting act.

Comment: Not related but came across [this article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/on-parenting/post/circumcision-and-why-pediatricians-are-offering-more-support/2012/08/27/1cdd5752-f06a-11e1-adc6-87dfa8eff430_blog.html) which says benefits of circumcision outweighs it disadvantages. I am not taking a position though, one way or the other.

Answer (score 5):

Your definition of "blasphemy" is wrong, but assuming you mean "against the rules of religion" , I will give you an answer.

**By your definition Circumcision & Education both are "Blasphemy"**

If "circumcision is blasphemy", wouldn't teaching a child to read and write be blasphemy too?

Humans are born illiterate and they will remain that way if they are not taught to read and write. There are millions of people in Africa, India, China who never learn to read or write, by your definition they are in "natural state".

**Allah's order is the rule**

In Islam, angels & jinns were ordered by Allah to bow to humans. This in no way means that we humans are superior in any way to Allah, but it simply was "Allah's order".

Similarly, it is Allah's order for us to remove the foreskin. Not removing the foreskin would be "blasphemy".

I would NOT call it "changing Allah's creation", but rather "following Allah's orders"

**Priority for Muslims**

There are many medical benefits to circumcision, but I can assure you, that for the millions of Muslims those medical benefits are secondary or may be even not of any importance, it is Allah's order that is of prime importance.

Comment: Teaching a child to read and write is adding something which wasn't there to start with - the ability to read and write.

Comment: yes but illiteracy is the natural form.... but then how about cutting hair or nails? may be they were meant to be grown long as its "natural form"

Comment: My question was addressing a biological part of the human body, put there by Allah. A baby isn't born with naturally long hair or nails, but this is a better argument;)

Comment: The "medical benefits" of circumcision remains a hotly disputed subject; it is not clearly decisive in either way, but historically, most of the "benefits" have been hugely exaggerated (or simply invented). But perhaps a better discussion on that is over on skeptics.SE: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/does-circumcision-lead-to-a-net-increase-in-quality-of-life or http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/does-circumcision-reduce-hiv-risk

Comment: whether exagerated or not , both sides agree that there are some benefits. As muslims our main benefit is not those medical benefits rather it is following all the prophets(pbut)

Comment: why did you say it is Allah's order? It has no mention in Quran. It is what Prophet Muhammad does, yes, but it is different from Allah's order.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this can be blasphemy since God commanded Prophet Ibraheem (Abraham) (pbuh) to do this as a test.  Which he did at the age of 80.  All prophets followed this after Prophet (Abraham) (pbuh), including prophet Eisa (Jesus) (pbuh) ([confirmed in the new testament (bible)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%202:21&version=NIV)) and prophet Mohammed (pbuh).

Here's a [fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/9412) if you're interested.