# What is the role of male circumcision in Islam?

Tags: circumcision

I’m wondering what forms of Islam practice this, and in what regions it is most prevalent.

I’m also wondering what its understood significance/ purpose is, as well as how it is practised: what age should the subject be, do they have a say in the matter, allowed/typically given anaesthesia, etc.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does Islam say about female circumcision?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7489/what-does-islam-say-about-female-circumcision)

Comment: Not really since I’m more wondering about male circumcision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is circumcision required in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/why-is-circumcision-required-in-islam)

Comment: Also see [What is the right age for circumcision?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/) for the second question. As for their say then it obviously is not relevant when they are young. As for anesthesia then it is permitted whether or not it is typically practiced is a question on medicine not religion.  Also please ask one focused question per post and research on your own before asking.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m wondering what forms of Islam practice this, and in what regions
> it is most prevalent.

It's prescribed. All Sunni, 12er and 5er Shia Muslim men circumcise, independently of the culture.

You find some rational explanations in the first answer to [Why is circumcision required in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/why-is-circumcision-required-in-islam).

Male circumcision was practised in Arabia (as well as in east Africa) before Muhammad. The tradition says that it goes back to Abraham.

Comment: What are 12er and 5er?

Comment: 12er Shia is the main shia sect -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam. 5er shia is a bit between sunni and 12er shia -> Zaydinism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaydism, , Ismailism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isma%27ilism